# Avoid the login popup when using http-auth

Tags: apache, url, http, authentication

I have an Apache. Under the DOCUMENTROOT is a folder with an .htpasswd file for http-auth. If I open the browser and request the content in the folder I get an Popup to login.

Is there a way to avoid the popup? I have tried to add the user and the password in the url:

```
http://user:passwd@domain.com/geheim
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work with every browser. Is there a workaround?
Thanks

Comment: [Don't rely upon basic HTTP authentication for security unless you are also using SSL.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Disadvantages)

Comment: What browser does not support this age old technique? Just curious.

Comment: @initall - An update to IE5.5 (or perhaps IE5.0), and all later versions of IE will not allow this type of link, for security reasons. I know some earlier versions of FireFox allowed it, but current versions of FireFox may not allow it.

Answer (score 1):

A GreaseMonkey solution to this was described over at StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55744/73652